# How to add strings in Oracle and create the text file with that string name

Tags: oracle, plsql

Below is my requirement:

- I want to generate a text file named as
  DBService_DateTimeStamp_UpgradeScipts.txt where
- DBService=> is the oracle service name against which the script is executed(dit/fit etc.)
- DateTimeStamp=>Current date time stamp upto seconds and
- UpgradeScipts->static text

Below is my script part:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE fileName VARCHAR2(100); 
  --Declare tStamp VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
  DECLARE fileName VARCHAR2(100); 
  Declare tStamp VARCHAR2(100);
  select sys_context('userenv','service_name') into fileName from dual;
  --SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP into tStamp FROM DUAL;
  --fileName:= fileName || '_' || tStamp; 
  --Dbms_Output.Put_Line('' || TIMESTAMP(3));
  --spool UpgradeClients.txt --here the desired file name should be like
  --  svc1_03-APR-17-12.51.12 AM.txt
END;
/
```

I think I am close to it, any help will be highly appretiated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
  fileName VARCHAR2(100) := SYS_CONTEXT('userenv','service_name')
                            || '_' || TO_CHAR( SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YY-HH24.MI.SS' )
                            || '_UpgradeScripts.txt';
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( fileName );
END;
/
```